# How to play a part of 24 hours video Web

Tags: web, video-streaming, media-player, wowza

I have 24 hours video, but based on users request I want to allow him watch only an interval of that video.
What player or what system should I use to achieve this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a schedule.

Take a look at [this](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?427-How-to-do-scheduled-streaming-with-Stream-class-streams-%28application-module%29).